Is the Net Force on the $y$-axis acting on a block is 0 when you slide a block upwards on a inclined slope?
In our physics class, we were tasked to answer this problem. A 5-kg block is moved up a 30 degree incline by a force of 50 N, parallel to the incline. The coefficient of kinetic friction between the block and the incline is 0.25. How much work is done by the 50 N force in moving the block a distance of 10 meters? What is the total work done on the block over the same distance?
After answering this question, our professor then showed his solution. I saw from his solution that he equated $Fnet$ in the $y$-axis to 0. Is his solution correct?

Your professor equating the net force in the Y-axis (perpendicular to the incline) to zero is correct. This is because there is no acceleration in the perpendicular direction to the incline, assuming the incline itself is stable and not moving. The normal force balances out the perpendicular component of the gravitational force, leading to zero net force in that direction. This is a standard approach in analyzing problems involving inclined planes where the motion is restricted to the plane itself.
